# Number(5) in Oracle what is it meaning in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, int, short

I created my table and one of my column area is Number(5),

```
 PROJECT_CODE  NUMBER(5)  NOT NULL ,
```

when i entegred it in my model in c# it is look like;

```
  public global::System.Int16 PROJECT_CODE
```

my question is why it is  getting to Int16 because int16 meaning short and max value is    **"32767"** if my value will be 32768 oracle will be okay but what about c#?

Comment: then why not change to `NUMBER(6)` or not specify the length at all?

Comment: sorry but i am not asking that i want to ask why c#  showing number(5) Int16 why it doesnt showing Int32

Comment: There is no direct correspondence between Oracle `Number(5)` which is *BCD* with `-99999..99999` range and Net *integer value*: `Int16` has `-32768..32767` or `Int32` has `-2147483648..2147483647`. Some compromise is inevitable.

Comment: This would be auto-mapping to the type, done by the data provider which can accommodate the value, for 32768 it will start mapping to Int32, since Int16 cannot accommodate the value any more

Comment: @MrinalKamboj you mean if value come for example 99999 from my client   , service side(I mean where is my model ) will change  int16 to int 32 automatic?

Comment: @Jenny Not that way in case it has the flexibility to decide the Type, else if you try to fill 32768 in Short (Int16), it will lead to an error

Comment: @MrinalKamboj thank you and i thought  maybe it was about that if c# let toInt32 it is meaning value will come more than Number(5) so maybe it was about that c# getting Int16 ?

Comment: @Jenny Ideally you shall use the type that work with your requirement, Code generation may not do a good job there

Comment: @MrinalKamboj yes you right but it was just simple example. I was wonder about how is oracle mapping working in c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because odpnet have a specification that inform of this state of fact.

[oracle datatype mapping for .net](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/entityDataTypeMapping.htm#ODPNT8300)

In code execution you can have an issue if you manually set a value with an incorrect range. I recommand to use same application to set value, that guarantee the process.